# SQL Server : update every 5 records with Past Months

Tags: sql-server

I want to update 15 records in that first 5 records date should be June 2019,next 5 records with July 2019,last 5 records with Aug 2019 based on employee id,Can any one tell me how to write this type of query in SQL Server Management Studio V 17.7,I've tried with below query but unable to do for next 5 rows..

**Like below query**

```
Update TOP(5) emp.employee(nolock) set statusDate=GETDATE()-31 where EMPLOYEEID='XCXXXXXX';
```

Comment: Can you give us more info on the table? I would think that EMPLOYEEID would be the primary key but your query seems to expect that there will be multiple rows with the same value.

Comment: EmployeeId is unique number for each employee,in this table each employee can have any number of records based on purchases.

Comment: What is the count of the rows in your table for each `EMPLOYEEID`?

Answer (score 0):

To update only a certain number of rows of a table you will need to include a FROM clause and join a sub-query which limits the number of rows. I would suggest using OFFSET AND FETCH instead of top so that you can skip X number of rows

You will also want to use the DATEADD function instead of directly subtracting a number from the DateTime function GETDATE(). I'm not certain but I think your query will subtract milliseconds. If you intend to go back a month I would suggest subtracting a month rather than 31 days. Alternatively it might be easier to specify an exact date like '2019-06-01'

For example:

TableA
- TableAID INT PK
- EmployeeID INT FK
- statusDate DATETIME

```
UPDATE TableA
SET statusDate = '2019-06-01'
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT TableAID
FROM TableA
WHERE EmployeeID = ''
ORDER BY TableAID
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
) T1 ON TableA.TableAID = T1.TableAID
```

Right now it looks like your original query is updating the table employee rather than a purchases table. You will want to replace my TableA with whichever table it is you're updating and replace TableAID with the PK field of it.

Comment: Thank you for answer but i don't want to use any joins and will it execute to next 5 rows and 5 rows etc?

Comment: I don't know of any way to limit the number of rows updated without using a join. In this query you would need to modify the OFFSET, FETCH, and Date used. Are you trying to update a large table in mass or what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ROW_NUMBER` to get a ranking by employee, then just update the first 15 rows.

```
;WITH EmployeeRowsWithRowNumbers AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        RowNumberByEmployee = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                T.EmployeeID -- Generate a ranking by each different EmployeeID
            ORDER BY 
                (SELECT NULL)) -- ... in no particular order (you should supply one if you have an ordering column)
    FROM
        emp.employee AS T
)
UPDATE E SET
    statusDate = CASE
        WHEN E.RowNumberByEmployee <= 5 THEN '2019-06-01'
        WHEN E.RowNumberByEmployee BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '2019-07-01'
        ELSE '2019-08-01' END
FROM
    EmployeeRowsWithRowNumbers AS E
WHERE
    E.RowNumberByEmployee <= 15
```